# how to configure Flex with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, flex3

I want to configure flex with Java.I have to create the project in which flex UI and JAVA serverside code.can any one tell me how to configure flex with Java using eclipse editor.

thanks in advance...............

Answer (score 0):

Check Flex Builder (plugin and standalone) from Adobe.
http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/
Its comes as Standalone Eclipse based IDE or you can download Eclipse plugin.
You can also find good tutorials (also video tutorials) for same on same link.

Comment: Is it possible to configre java also in flex builder?

Comment: Yes. Flex Builder comes with Java eclipse plugin.

Comment: were you successful in installing flex builder and using same ?

Comment: @Vipin Nemade did you find what you wanted ?